# How to auto scroll up Recycler view in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have developed some chat application where i can send and received messages. But the problem is whenever i send or receive messages the recycler view is not scrolling to top so that messages gets diplayed above the keypad.

I have used the above mentioned recycler view `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On updating recyclerview try to run this code :

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Call smooth scroll  
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);                                 
    }
});
```

Comment: It will scroll your recyclerview to latest item added.

Comment: It should be `adapter.getItemCount() - 1`. It will scroll too fast otherwise since the scrolling distance will be calculated with a non existing item in mind.

Comment: It'll be fast. What if we want to scroll smoothly so anyone can look at each item of the `ViewGroup`

Comment: how can we achieve scroll slow

Answer (score 9):

I use the following code so that the scroll is automatic until the last position:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
```

I implement to add a new item to the list.

Answer (score 3):

Try the bellow method for auto scroll to your particular position.

```
adapter = new DeliveriesDateRecycleAdapter(getActivity(),sampleDatedate, position);
                recyclerviewDates.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerviewDates.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

**Note** : position - the position of the list that you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `RecyclerView.srollTo(int x, int y)`?

Edit: Try `RecyclerView.scrollTo(0, 0)` directly after you have send or received the last message.

Comment: No i have not tried. Can you explain it with some example

Comment: //Scroll item 3 to 20 pixels from the top
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(3, 20);

Answer (score 0):

try with following method for auto scroll to any position....you can change argument of the "notifyItemChanged" method.

```
 public void printer(String message){
    block block=new block();
    block.details=message;

    blocks.add(block);

    blockAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(blocks.size()-1);
   // recyclerView.scrollTo(blocks.size()-1,blocks.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using horizontal recycler view with linear layout manager ,accepted solution didn't work for me

But below solution worked,

```
(recycler.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your user directly to the latest item **without scroll** animation then use this:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1);
```