# Android Firebase chat RecyclerView auto scroll to bottom when new item is added

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

im developing an android chat using firebase.

i tried to research about this problem but i cant find a good solutions.

hope someone can help me.

my problem i want the RecyclerView to auto scroll if new item is added.

here is my code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlayoutchat, container, false);

    Connectivity connectivity=new Connectivity();
    if(connectivity.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        if(getArguments() != null) {
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());
            String ccustomersid = getArguments().getString("customersid");
            String creferralae = getArguments().getString("referralae");
            String ccustomersname = getArguments().getString("customersname");

            customersid = ccustomersid;
            referralae = creferralae;
            customersname = ccustomersname;

            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getActivity());


            editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

            sendbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmgr = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmgr);
            mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            //linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            from_user = customersid;
            to_user = referralae;
            LoggedInUser = customersname;


            //Log.v("NODE CREATED:", from_user + " " + to_user);


            ref_chatchildnode1 = firebase_chatnode.child(from_user + " " + to_user);

            //ref_chatchildnode2 = firebase_chatnode.child(to_user + " " + from_user);
            sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    newmsg = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                    ChatModel m = new ChatModel();
                    m.setSender(LoggedInUser);
                    m.setMessage(newmsg);
                    ref_chatchildnode1.push().setValue(m);
                    //ref_chatchildnode2.push().setValue(m);
                    editText.setText("");


                }
            });
            ref_chatchildnode1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    ChatModel chatmsg = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
                    chatmsgsList.add(chatmsg);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

    }else{
        nointernet();
    }

    showGlobalContextActionBar();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAdapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, ChatMessageViewHolder>(ChatModel.class,
            R.layout.textview,
            ChatMessageViewHolder.class,
            ref_chatchildnode1) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageViewHolder chatMessageViewHolder, ChatModel m, int i) {



            chatMessageViewHolder.sender.setText(m.getSender());
            chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());

        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter1);

}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have a look at [step 6 of the Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#6), which uses an `AdapterDataObserver` for this:

```
mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
   @Override
   public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
       super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
       int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
       int lastVisiblePosition =
              mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
       // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the 
       // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom 
       // of the list to show the newly added message.
       if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
               (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                       lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
           mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: That will scroll if you add 1 new message. if you have 6 unread messages and you click to read them, it will show first unread message and the rest 5 you will have to scroll manually to view to the bottom

Comment: Using `if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 || positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1))` fixes this problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            
         CommentRv.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount.minus(1))
        }
    })
```

Comment: Worked absolutely fine. No other answer worked.

Comment: Yes. Worked absolutely fine. No other answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just try below code :

```
         @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                mFirebaseAdapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, ChatMessageViewHolder>(ChatModel.class,
                        R.layout.textview,
                        ChatMessageViewHolder.class,
                        ref_chatchildnode1) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageViewHolder chatMessageViewHolder, ChatModel m, int i) {



                        chatMessageViewHolder.sender.setText(m.getSender());
                        chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());

                    }
                };
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter1);

        if (mFirebaseAdapter1 != null) { 
                    mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() { 
                         mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mFirebaseAdapter1.getItemCount() - 1);
                     }
                  }, 5); 
              }
            }
```

Comment: After set adapter in RecyclerView and below add it.

Comment: Sorry.. setSelection replace to smoothScrollToPosition and getCount replace to getItemCount()

Comment: im getting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229806/how-to-auto-scroll-up-recycler-view-in-android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128987/discussion-between-manikandan-k-and-joehamir).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old thread, but maybe this will be helpful.

In place where you add new message:

```
yourRVAdapter.addMessage("New message")
val position = yourRVAdapter.itemCount.minus(1) // itemCount will return the size of RV items 
//Now just call your recyclerView.scrollToPosition(int)
chatRV.scrollToPosition(position)
```

Comment: This will not always work: adding in base is not instant so what will most likely happen is that it will take number BEFORE it was added and scroll to that item not to item +1

Answer (score 1):

If you working with reversedLayout "chat interface" specially if you have images, you can try the following:

first, register DataObserver with the adapter

```
   chatAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : 
                         RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

   override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int itemCount: Int) {

      val messageCount: Int = chatAdapter.itemCount

      val lastVisiblePosition: Int =
            layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

         if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 || positionStart <= (messageCount - 1)) {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart)
        }
    }
})
```

this will be called once you set the data for the adapter

second, you have to add a scroll listener to the recyclerView like this:

```
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object 
     :RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

       override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: 
          Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

          val lastVisiblePosition: Int =
              layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
        if (lastVisiblePosition != -1 && lastVisiblePosition < 
                chatAdapter.itemCount - 1) {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
})
```